# How do Appengine Queue Buckets Fill?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, task-queue

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Defining_Push_Queues_and_Processing_Rates):

> App Engine refills the bucket with new tokens continuously based on the rate that you specified for the queue.

I am unclear by what is meant by the word continuously here.  Does it mean that tokens are added one at a time at `(rate_magnitude/rate_unit)` or are all the tokens dumped in at one time once every `rate_unit`?

To be clear, if I have a queue.yaml as follows.  Will I get a dump of 60 tokens (and therefore request filled) once an hour, or is it equivalent to having rate set to `1/m`?

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 60/h
 ...
```

And if it is a dump every unit of time, what happens if my `bucket_size` is less than the magnitude of `rate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens are added one at a time. Regardless of the bucket size, there is no difference between rates of 1 per minute and 60 per hour, or between 0.1 per minute and 6 per hour.